# Replace previous database backup by new one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I use this script for getting backup from my sql server databases

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name 
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files 
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup 
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name

--Path to backups
SET @path = 'E:\DataBase Backups\' 

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb','ReportServer','ReportServerTempDB') 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       --Remove if you dont want a date stamp 
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK' 

      -- SET @fileName = @path + @name + '.BAK' 
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName with noinit

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This code makes new backup file per day, but I need to replace my old backup by today backup or after making today's backup, all old backups became deleted!
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an undocumented extended stored procedure, xp_delete_file, to delete your backup files.  Microsoft has internally added some safeguards to allow it to only delete database and transaction log backup files.  So it can't be used to delete any other file types; not even text files.

You need to declare a few extra variables.

```
DECLARE @DeleteDate datetime = DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE())
DECLARE @FileExtension nvarchar(3) = N'BAK'
DECLARE @DeletePath nvarchar(512)
```

Then add this code to your cursor loop.

```
SET @DeletePath = @path + @name
EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_file 0,@DeletePath,@FileExtension,@DeleteDate,1;
```

@DeleteDate is what you use to tell the stored procedure which files to delete that are older than a certain date.  Just use the DATEADD function to set the cutoff date.

@DeletePath will be your @path + @name so it will output something like 'E:\DataBase Backups\MyDatabaseName'.

@FileExtention is used to tell what file types to delete; for example BAK' or 'TRN'.

I have been using this same code to purge old backup files in my custom TSQL backup jobs and it works great.